# Find all values of $r \ge 0$ such that $x_n = \frac{r^n}{r^n + 1}$ is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I figured that the best way to solve this would be to find all values of $r$ for which $x_n$ converges because, by definition, convergent sequences are Cauchy.

Is it sufficient to say that

- when $r \lt 1$, the sequence converges to $\frac{0}{0 + 1} = 0$
- when $r = 1$, the sequence converges to $\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{1^n}} = \frac12$
- when $r \gt 1$, the sequence converges to $\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{r^n}} = 1$

And thus, $\forall r \ge 0, x_n$ is Cauchy?

Comment: Here's something that may make it simpler: $$\frac{r^n}{r^n+1} = \frac{r^n+1-1}{r^n+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{r^n+1}.$$

Comment: Is this for real/complex numbers. In this case the sequence is Cauchy iff it is convergent. So ehat you have seems fine. But why conclude $r\geq 0$?

Comment: @Any the problem stated to find the values of $r \ge 0$ for which it was Cauchy, and I found that it's Cauchy for all $r \ge 0$ through the three cases I specified above.

Comment: It is not by definition that convergent sequences are Cauchy, it's a result. But yes, you have proved the result.

Answer (score 1):

The poster of this problem has given a correct solution.So the answer to his question -"Is this correct " is Yes .